# Linq syntax with group by and having clauses

Tags: c#, linq

I try to get a list from a datatable by a linq syntax with having clause.

But I don't get what I want.

Here's the SQL syntax :

```
SELECT ID_BEN,
        GAR1,
        FIRST(FIRST_NAME) FIRST_NAME,
        FIRST(LAST_NAME) LAST_NAME,
        FIRST(ADR1) ADR1,
        FIRST(ADR2) ADR2,
        FIRST(ZIP_CODE) ZIP_CODE,
        FIRST(CITY) CITY,
        SUM(AMOUNT) SUM_AMOUNT,
    SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS_TAB <> 'OK' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) NUM_STATUS_TAB
    FROM T_AMOUNT
    WHERE STATUS_ENR = 'OK' AND STATE_ENR = '1'
    GROUP BY ID_BEN, GAR1
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS_TAB <> 'OK' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

Here is my linq syntax :

```
var oLstReglementGrp = objDataSet.T_AMOUNT
                      .AsEnumerable()
                      .Select(sel => new
                       {
                           ID_BEN = sel.ID_BEN,
                           GAR1 = sel.GAR1,
                           LI_NOM = sel.First().FIRST_NAME,
                           LI_ADR1 = sel.First().LAST_NAME,
                           LI_ADR2 = sel.First().ADR1,
                           LI_ADR3 = sel.First().ADR2,
                           LI_ADR4 = sel.First().ZIP_CODE,
                           CD_PST = sel.First().CITY
                           
                       })
                     .Where(x => x.STATUS_ENR == "OK"
                          && x.STATE_ENR == "1")
                      .GroupBy(row => new { ID_BEN = (long?)row.ID_BEN, GAR1 = row.GAR1 },
                      (g, r) => new
                      {
                          NUM_STATUS_TAB = r.Sum(s => s.STATUS_TAB != "OK" ? 1 : 0),
                          SUM_AMOUNT = r.Sum(s => (decimal?)s.AMOUNT)
                      })
                      .Where(p => p.NUM_STATUS_TAB == 0)
                      .ToList();
```

Here are the SQL results :

```
FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME   ADR1        ZIP_CODE    CITY        SUM_AMOUNT  NUM_STATUS_TAB
Jack        Palance     3 bd One    1234        New York    12000       0   
John        Wayne       4 ave 2     4567        Los Angeles 5500        0           
Jimmy       Page        5 street 2  2345        Chicago     450         0
```

And in my list from the linq :

```
SUM_AMOUNT  NUM_STATUS_TAB
12000       0   
5500        0           
450         0
```

Do you have an idea ?

Comment: Can you tell us what your problem is? What does it give you, are there any errors? Can you be more specific in what is currently the problem?

Comment: "But I don't get what I want." What do you want? What do you get instead?

Comment: Glubus, Somebody : I tried to translate the Sql above into linq syntax but with no success. Instead with the linq I don't get the fields I put in the select but only the fields I put in the group by.

Comment: Hey Eric, could you maybe copy paste the desired output from the SQL query, and the actual output from your LINQ query in your question so we can actually see what you are talking about? It will help us understand what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: When you call `AsEnumerable()`, you are trying to do the LINQ in memory rather than in database.

Comment: My guest is that you try to respect the Sql syntax when wrote the linq. LinQ syntax is closer to the order of execution of SQL. EG The tabLe> The filter before groupby> Groupby > Select > filter after group by .

Comment: xdtTransform : thanks for your comment.
I tried what you say but as soon as I put the GroupBy block before the Select block, all the fields in the select block were in error as if it didn't recognize the fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing LinQ you should no try to translate to SQL query like you would read it.
LinQ syntax is closer to SQL Execution order. In this way Linq is more "Logical".

SQL execution order is the following:

1. FROM and JOINs
2. WHERE
3. GROUP BY
4. HAVING
5. SELECT

```
objDataSet
    // 1. FROM and JOINs
    .T_AMOUNT   
    
    //2. WHERE  
    .Where(x => x.STATUS_ENR == "OK" && x.STATE_ENR == "1") 
    
    //3. GROUP BY 
    .GroupBy(row => new { ID_BEN = (long?)row.ID_BEN, GAR1 = row.GAR1 })
    
    //5. SELECT 
    .Select(sel => new
    {
        ID_BEN = sel.Key.ID_BEN,
        GAR1 = sel.Key.GAR1,
        LI_NOM = sel.First().FIRST_NAME,
        LI_ADR1 = sel.First().LAST_NAME,
        LI_ADR2 = sel.First().ADR1,
        LI_ADR3 = sel.First().ADR2,
        LI_ADR4 = sel.First().ZIP_CODE,
        CD_PST = sel.First().CITY,
        NUM_STATUS_TAB = sel.Sum(s => s.STATUS_TAB != "OK" ? 1 : 0),
        SUM_AMOUNT = sel.Sum(s => (decimal?)s.AMOUNT)
    })
    
    //4. HAVING
    .Where(p => p.NUM_STATUS_TAB == 0)
    .ToList();
```

Step 4 and 5 have been swap because we are filtering on a field that is not present in the groupby, so we need the select in order to have it avaidable.

At Step 3. GROUP BY, notice the overload used. Order by has 9 overload, [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?).
I will advice on using the simple one till you get familiar with it

Comment: xdtTransform : I tried what you put.
But when I put the Select before the Having, all the field are not recognized. It seems that the Select must be at the last position.
But when I put the Select in the last position the Having doesn't recognize NUM_STATUS_TAB.

Comment: xdtTranform : Sorry, I have missed the First() statement in the Select clause, that's why it didn't work.
Now it works perfectly, thanks to your explanations.
Thanks a lot again !